# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '���'

Tags: python, numpy, pyspark, python-unicode

I have a (2M, 23) dimensional `numpy` array `X`. It has a dtype of `<U26`, i.e. unicode string of 26 characters.

```
array([['143347', '1325', '28.19148936', ..., '61', '0', '0'],
   ['50905', '0', '0', ..., '110', '0', '0'],
   ['143899', '1325', '28.80434783', ..., '61', '0', '0'],
   ...,
   ['85', '0', '0', ..., '1980', '0', '0'],
   ['233', '54', '27', ..., '-1', '0', '0'],
   ['���', '�', '�����', ..., '�', '��', '���']], dtype='<U26')
```

When I convert it to a float datatype, using

```
X_f = X.astype(float)
```

I get the error as shown above. I am trying to find how to solve this string formatting error for '���'.

What does it mean (what is it called?) and how do I solve this error?

EDIT: Information on how the data was read:-

#### importing relevant packages

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
```

#### loading the dataset in a pyspark dataframe

```
def loading_data(dataset):
    dataset=sql_sc.read.format('csv').options(header='true', inferSchema='true').load(dataset)
    # #changing column header name
    dataset = dataset.select(*[col(s).alias('Label') if s == ' Label' else s for s in dataset.columns])
    #to change datatype
    dataset=dataset.drop('External IP')
    dataset = dataset.filter(dataset.Label.isNotNull())
    dataset=dataset.filter(dataset.Label!=' Label')#filter Label from label
    print(dataset.groupBy('Label').count().collect())
    return dataset

# invoking
ds_path = '../final.csv'
dataset=loading_data(ds_path)
```

#### check type of dataset.

```
type(dataset)
```

pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame

#### convert to np array

```
import numpy as np
np_dfr = np.array(data_preprocessing(dataset).collect())
```

#### split features and labels

```
X = np_dfr[:,0:22]
Y = np_dfr[:,-1]
```

#### show X

```
>> X
array([['143347', '1325', '28.19148936', ..., '61', '0', '0'],
       ['50905', '0', '0', ..., '110', '0', '0'],
       ['143899', '1325', '28.80434783', ..., '61', '0', '0'],
       ...,
       ['85', '0', '0', ..., '1980', '0', '0'],
       ['233', '54', '27', ..., '-1', '0', '0'],
       ['���', '�', '�����', ..., '�', '��', '���']], dtype='<U26')
```

Comment: How do you read that data?`�` is the Unicode replacement character, used when ASCII text is read using the wrong codepage. Looks like the source contained non-numeric data that was read using the wrong codepage. Even if the correct codepage was used, the text would still be invalid

Comment: If you were the Python interpreter, how would you convert `'���'` to float? Which number would that represent? What is your desired result?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: i read it from a pyspark dataframe using `collect()` method.

Comment: @zvone: exactly! I wish I knew what the URC(???) was before. Desired result is a numpy array of float values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though not the best solution, I found some success by converting it into pandas dataframe and working along.

#### code snippet

```
# convert X into dataframe
X_pd = pd.DataFrame(data=X)
# replace all instances of URC with 0 
X_replace = X_pd.replace('�',0, regex=True)
# convert it back to numpy array
X_np = X_replace.values
# set the object type as float
X_fa = X_np.astype(float)
```

#### input

```
array([['85', '0', '0', '1980', '0', '0'],
       ['233', '54', '27', '-1', '0', '0'],
       ['���', '�', '�����', '�', '��', '���']], dtype='<U5')
```

#### output

```
array([[ 8.50e+01,  0.00e+00,  0.00e+00,  1.98e+03,  0.00e+00,  0.00e+00],
       [ 2.33e+02,  5.40e+01,  2.70e+01, -1.00e+00,  0.00e+00,  0.00e+00],
       [ 0.00e+00,  0.00e+00,  0.00e+00,  0.00e+00,  0.00e+00,  0.00e+00]])
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that string(���) dimension is not fixed in the graph and it can vary between run calls
The Question mark Symbol indicates `tf.TensorShape` 
Any tensor returned by Session.run or eval is a NumPy array.

```
>>> print(type(tf.Session().run(tf.constant([1,2,3]))))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Or:

```
>>> sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
>>> print(type(tf.constant([1,2,3]).eval()))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Or, equivalently:

```
>>> sess = tf.Session()
>>> with sess.as_default():
>>>    print(type(tf.constant([1,2,3]).eval()))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

**Not** any tensor returned by Session.run or eval() is a NumPy array. Sparse Tensors for example are returned as SparseTensorValue:

```
>>> print(type(tf.Session().run(tf.SparseTensor([[0, 0]],[1],[1,2]))))
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensorValue'>
```